# Half of my app is cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to create an app using the [DevFright MapKit tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/#more-566). My problem is that when I run the app, some of it is cut off, like the bottom part and to the right. I was told I need to learn about constraints but I think the problem might be autolayout. Thanks!
[image: Simulator image with the right and bottom cut off]

Comment: Constraints are a part of auto-layout. I agree with whoever told you that you need to learn about the subject. This question is currently lacking key details (the description of your storyboard and layout elements).

Comment: Stanfords CS193p has its first few lectures of the year up already on iTunes U, they cover auto layout in the first few lectures, it might help.

Comment: @IanMacDonald what kind of details can I add on?

Comment: @meghan66: set autolayout to autoresize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do two things to get my apps to work again:

1. I had to change the width and height to compact and any. That is because I am still testing on the iPhone 5. Once I fixed that, most of my buttons showed up (I figured this out while making another app).
2. I had to add constraints by selecting the button and going to Editor -> Pin -> and then three of four, Leading Space to Superview, Trailing Space to Superview, Top Space to Superview, and/or Bottom Space to Superview. I had to put three constraints for each button. I discovered this with [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich

Answer (score 0):

It's both: constraints in autolayout

Are you using storyboard or did you build the view programmatically?

For Storyboard, view CS193p iOS 8 Apps with Swift video 2. Set the constraints to attach themselves to the boundary of the device.

For programmatic implementations, try using Visual Markup Language.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to look into [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) to deal with constrains.